# Is it possible to track who is running SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, diagnostic, sql-server

Is it possible to see who is running SQL Server Profiler against a certain database and possibly from what machine?  Say through Profiler itself or by T-SQL statement.

I wonder if it is even possible to find out Active Directly user name under which the profiler is running.

---

**[UPDATE]**
As a reference, here is a way to retrieve only SQL Server Profile processes

```
declare @sp_who2 table (
    SPID    int,
    status  varchar(50),
    login   varchar(100),
    HostName    varchar(100),
    BlkBy   varchar(100),
    DBName  varchar(100),
    Command varchar(100),
    CPUTime int,
    DiskIO  int,
    LastBatch   varchar(50),
    ProgramName varchar(150),
    SPID2   int,
    REQUESTID   int
)
insert  @sp_who2
exec sp_who2

select  *
from    @sp_who2
where   ProgramName like 'SQL Server Profiler - %'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute

**sp_who2**

Look at the ProgramName column and you will see something like SQL Server Profiler - 362b6154-2d69-4ce0-987b-2573bed3ce45. From that query you can define a user name and HostName...

Answer (score 2):

use SQL Profiler and look for existing connection and login events from application name "`SQL Server Profiler - {guid}`" where {guid} varies by run (and by default SQL Profiler runs exclude themselves based on its own application name.

Comment: I was wondering what the jumbled up characters meant. It was "guid".  Thank you, richard.